# Split nested and simple comma lists the same way

Tags: split, key-value

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys,kvdefinekeys}
\makeatletter

\def\Process@Split#1{%
  \if@tempswa
    \edef\ST@LastName{\comma@entry}% 
    \typeout{* LastName:\ST@LastName}%
    \@tempswafalse   
  \else
    \edef\ST@FirstName{\comma@entry}%
    \typeout{* FirstName:\ST@FirstName}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*\Split@Name[1]{
  \begingroup
    \@tempswatrue
    \expandafter\comma@parse\expandafter{#1}{\Process@Split}
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*\Process@Authors[1]{%
  \typeout{>>>>>\comma@entry<<<<<}
  \Split@Name{\comma@entry} 
}

\kv@define@key{ST}{author}{%
  \def\ST@author{#1}%
}
\kv@define@key{ST}{foo}{%
  % ...
}

\newcommand\Test[1][]{
  \kvsetkeys{ST}{#1}%
  \expandafter\comma@parse\expandafter{\ST@author}{\Process@Authors}
}

\begin{document}         
\Test[%
  author={{LastName1A, FirstName1A},{LastName2B,FirstName2B}},
  foo=bla
]
\Test[%
  author={LastName1C, FirstName1C},
  foo=bla
]
\end{document}
```

In the example above, I would like to use the author key for one or for more authors and split each author into first and last names. The example does not work correctly for only one author. Is there a solution where I don't

`author={{LastName1C, FirstName1C}}`

have to write? I would like to keep the `kvsetkeys` package. Thanks in advance.

Rolf

Comment: I'm afraid there is no fool proof way here, but you could count the number of list elements, if it equals two check that both elements aren't lists of two elements, if that's the case you got a single author, else you got multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following implements the checks outlined in my comment using two `expl3` functions (`\clist_count:n` and `\clist_item:nn`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys,kvdefinekeys}
\makeatletter

\def\Process@Split#1{%
  \if@tempswa
    \edef\ST@LastName{\comma@entry}% 
    \typeout{* LastName:\ST@LastName}%
    \@tempswafalse   
  \else
    \edef\ST@FirstName{\comma@entry}%
    \typeout{* FirstName:\ST@FirstName}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*\Split@Name[1]{
  \begingroup
    \@tempswatrue
    \expandafter\comma@parse\expandafter{#1}{\Process@Split}
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*\Process@Authors[1]{%
  \typeout{>>>>>\comma@entry<<<<<}
  \Split@Name{\comma@entry} 
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \ST@count@authors \clist_count:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \ST@authors@access \clist_item:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\kv@define@key{ST}{author}{%
  \ifnum\ST@count@authors{#1}=2
    \ifnum\expandafter\ST@count@authors\expanded{{\ST@authors@access{#1}{1}}}=2
      \def\ST@author{#1}%
    \else
      \ifnum\expandafter\ST@count@authors\expanded{{\ST@authors@access{#1}{2}}}=2
        \def\ST@author{#1}%
      \else
        \def\ST@author{{#1}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \def\ST@author{#1}%
  \fi
}
\kv@define@key{ST}{foo}{%
  % ...
}

\newcommand\Test[1][]{
  \kvsetkeys{ST}{#1}%
  \expandafter\comma@parse\expandafter{\ST@author}{\Process@Authors}
}

\begin{document}         
\Test[%
  author={{LastName1A, FirstName1A},{LastName2B,FirstName2B}},
  foo=bla
]
\Test[%
  author={LastName1C, FirstName1C},
  foo=bla
]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It's a clever solution.